# Need assistance with extracting separate cells from range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I'm facing difficulty with the following and would greatly appreciate advice or a solution. Please see below for details.

1. I have a range, E43:BV131. E43:BV43 = header, E43:E131 = name column
2. Cells F44:BV131 contain mainly 4 types of information: either letters "R" or "A" or "G"; or some text in a cell adjacent to an "R" or "A". Example table below.
3. My task is to extract all cells with "R"/"A" and the text in the adjacent cell.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I need:

1. For "R" status

[image]

2. For "A" status

[image]

Tried multiple combinations of OFFSET, INDIRECT, INDEX, ROW, COLUMN and a bunch of formulas from found on the web, however, all the documentation I'm finding works around columns whereas I need to extract data from random cells across the table.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line of "Criteria" above "Output header" in row 6

1] In `A8`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/($B$2:$M$4=B$6),ROW(A1))),"")
```

2] In `B8`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A8="","",B$6)
```

3] In `C8`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A8="","",INDEX($B$2:$M$4,MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B$6,INDEX($B$2:$M$4,MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),0)+1))
```

Then, select `A8:C9`, copied and paste formula to `F8:H9`

[image]

Comment: Hi, Bosco
Thank you for the solution! I tried to make it work and almost did, but the issue I'm facing now is that when I use it on a range based on another sheet - it doesn't work correctly for some reason and I can't seem to understand the catch.
I used your formulas and only changed sheet name and range.

Comment: The comments return either N/A or duplicated names/comments.
Here's a screenshot https://paste.pics/G3LRH
A13:C23 On the left that's your original formula and it works properly, on the right: my changes with sheet and range change and the inaccurate result.

Do you perhaps know what could be the cause of this?

When I post exactly your formula and only change the sheet name - everything works correctly.

Comment: Hi again)

I keep trying out your solution with the original formula and this is what I found:
It only posts the first comment on the current line, so if I have more than 1 Rs in a line, I will still only fetch the first comment and it will be posted for all Rs in the output list.

https://paste.pics/G3MFQ

Is there a way to battle this?

Thx